# Adding 'N' no of years to Date in database

Tags: php, date

Insert Query

```
 $product= "INSERT INTO `products`
        (`id`, `code`, `cat`, `type`, `desc`, `serial_no`, `product_model_no`, `vendor`, `invoice`, `purchased_date`, `warranty`, `exp_date`, `remarks`, `status`, `modified_date`) VALUES 
        (' ','$code','$cat','$type','$desc','$serial_no','$model_no','$vendor','$invoice','$purchased_date','$warranty','$exp_date', 'In Warranty', '$remarks','1',' ' );";
        $add= mysqli_query($con, $product) or die(mysqli_error($con));;
```

UI

```
<select name="warranty">
    <option value="+1 day">1 Day</option>
    <option value="+1 week">1 Week</option>
    <option value="+6 months">06 Months</option>
    <option value="+1 year">12 Months</option>
    <option value="+1 year 6 months">18 Months</option>
    <option value="+2 years">24 Months</option>
    <option value="+3 years">36 Months</option>
    <option value="+5 years">60 Months</option>

    <?php $start_date = $purchased_date;
    $targetDate = date(strtotime("'.warranty.'") $start_date);
    echo $targetDate;?>
    </select>
```

Date is inserted in database with `$purchased_date` variable. After inserting date it should calculate warranty with the above select and insert warranty status  into database so that i can list out out of warranty asserts..

I've tried the above code and don't know where I'm wrong. Please help me.

DB Querys

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $updt_wrnty= "UPDATE `products` SET `exp_date`='$targetDate';";
    $wrnty= mysqli_query($con, $updt_wrnty) or die(mysqli_error($con));;
```

Comment: So, what do you expect to happen and what happens now? We should predict it?

Answer (score 1):

Your order of arguments is wrong. If you want to add a time period to a certain date, you need to use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) form:

```
date(strtotime($product_warranty, $start_date))
```

Comment: I want to add both at a time.. while adding product I will select date and warranty period.. It should calculate the warranty expiry date and insert it to database..
this the functionality I'm trying to achieve..

Comment: Right now, you're only showing your UI code. If you want us to fix your database code, you'll also have to include that part of the code. Otherwise it's going to be very hard for us.